C# Spreadsheetlight - How to select 2 columns as X axis data
So I want to somehow group bussines year column (column B) with Output period column (column C) so both values can be shown on X axis of a clusteredcolumn chart in spreadsheetlight.
This is the table:

Creating chart: (this is currently now starting from C column because it needs to look like this but with added years under quartals on X axis)
chart = sl.CreateChart("C62", "F81", new SLCreateChartOptions() { RowsAsDataSeries = false, ShowHiddenData = false });
        chart.SetChartType(SLColumnChartType.ClusteredColumn);
        chart.PlotDataSeriesAsPrimaryLineChart(3, SLChartDataDisplayType.Normal, false);

This is current chart:

The chart I get when I try to create when starting from B column:

This is what I need to get and which I get when I select manually data range from B column in Excel/Libre Calc:

